# MVCContrib TestHelper problem with session.clear, session.abandon and Rhino Mock

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, nunit, rhino-mocks, mvccontrib-testhelper

Hi I'm trying to unit test my logout action on my controller but I have hard times to test or stub my Session in the HttpContext. I'm using [MVC Contrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) to make it easier but now I need a little help.

Here's my test :

```
[TestFixture]
    public class SessionControllerTest
    {
        private ISession _session;
        private IConfigHelper _configHelper;
        private IAuthenticationService _authService;
        //private IMailHelper _mailHelper;
        private ICryptographer _crypto;
        private SessionController _controller;
        private TestControllerBuilder _builder;
        private MockRepository _mock;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mock = new MockRepository();
        _session = _mock.DynamicMock<ISession>();
        _configHelper = _mock.DynamicMock<IConfigHelper>();
        _authService = _mock.DynamicMock<IAuthenticationService>();
        //_mailHelper = _mock.DynamicMock<IMailHelper>();
        _crypto = _mock.DynamicMock<ICryptographer>();
        _controller = new SessionController(_authService, _session, _crypto, _configHelper);
        _builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
        _builder.InitializeController(_controller);
    }
[Test]
        public void Logout_ReturnRedirectToAction()
        {
        _builder.InitializeController(_controller);

        _authService.SignOut();
        LastCall.Repeat.Once();
        _builder.Session["memberNumber"] = string.Empty;
        LastCall.Repeat.Once();
        _controller.Session.Clear();
        LastCall.Repeat.Any();
        _controller.Session.Abandon();
        LastCall.Repeat.Any();
        //_builder.Session.Stub(s => s.Clear());
        //_builder.Session.Stub(s => s.Abandon());
        //_builder.Session.Clear();
        //LastCall.Repeat.Once();
        //_builder.Session.Abandon();
        //LastCall.Repeat.Once();

        _mock.ReplayAll();
        var result = _controller.Logout();

        _mock.VerifyAll();
        result.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction<SessionController>(c => c.Login());
    }
```

You can see my differents attemps. I get an error telling me that Session.Abandon() is not implemented, witch is right when you take a look at MVCContrib's TestHelper. But how can I mock or Stub the Session that's already mocked by the TestHelper?

The Exception in NUnit :

> System.NotImplementedException : The
>   method or operation is not
>   implemented. at
>   MvcContrib.TestHelper.MockSession.Abandon()

Thank you for the help!

EDIT : Here's the new working test

```
[Test]
    public void Logout_ReturnRedirectToAction()
    {
        _builder.InitializeController(_controller);
        var mockSession = _mock.Stub<HttpSessionStateBase>();

        _controller.HttpContext.BackToRecord();
        _controller.HttpContext.Stub(c => c.Session).Return(mockSession);
        _controller.HttpContext.Replay();

        _authService.SignOut();
        LastCall.Repeat.Once();
        _builder.Session["memberNumber"] = string.Empty;
        _controller.Session.Clear();
        LastCall.Repeat.Once();
        _controller.Session.Abandon();
        LastCall.Repeat.Once();

        _mock.ReplayAll();
        var result = _controller.Logout();

        _mock.VerifyAll();
        result.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction<SessionController>(c => c.Login());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I used MvcContrib, so I pulled down the latest code and made a quick test project.  It's very odd.  Looking at the MvcContrib code (specifically, TestControllerBuilder), it creates mocks for most of the objects (request, response, server, etc...), but not for Session.  I'm not sure why this is -- probably have to ask the creators.

However, there is a way to mock it yourself.  You can create your own mock session and tell the controller to use yours instead of the one from MvcContrib.TestHelpers.  Here's what I did in my test:

```
var mockSession = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpSessionStateBase>();
controller.HttpContext.BackToRecord();
controller.HttpContext.Stub(c => c.Session).Return(mockSession);
controller.HttpContext.Replay();
```

Now I run my controller method and then use Rhino.Mocks' AAA syntax for making sure the Abandon method was called:

```
controller.Session.AssertWasCalled(s => s.Abandon());
```

If you want to use record/replay semantics, you could set your expectations before calling `controller.HttpContext.Replay()`.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, it works great! I did not knew about the BackToRecord().